# NetBeans doesn't include Test libraries and Test package when creating new Java project

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm learning Java using Apache NetBeans 12.3 with JDK 15. When I created a new Java Application (Java with Ant) today for some reason the created project has only 2 packages. Even though the other project that I created days before used to have 4 packages, the missing packages are Test Packages and Test Libraries. How can I fix this problem so that when I create a new project it will have Test Packages and Test Libraries?

[image]

Comment: Why **Ant**, have you considered **Java with Maven** project? Then you get all the dependencies needed.